# Displaying images in an iOS web view through a URL in an sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am very new to sqlite and I need help. I have looked a lot on the net, in books and within Stack Overflow for a solution to my problem, but so far no cigar.

I have some text saved in an Sqlite database that I display in a webview and I would like to add a photo once every 50 lines of so. The photos themselves would reside in a server. According to tutorials I found on the net, regular HTML like

```
<img src="http://rempu.modwest.com/photo/SS.png" alt="some_text">
```

embedded in the text should work in sqlite but I get only the missing image icon. The fact the icon appears at all seems to indicate that the HTML is understood and the problem is the URL. I have tried relative URLs with local files, absolute ones with remote files but nothing works even with paths I know to be correct.
.
Lots of Stack Overload pages suggest to use URLs rather than BLOBS for images in sqlite, none I found explains HOW this is done. Anybody can help? I apologise in advance if my question is dumb.
Thanks, 
Frank

Comment: Update your question with some actual HTML you load into your web view showing an actual `img` tag with the remote URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question isn't dumb, but it is a little confusing. If I understand it correctly, you're trying to display images with some alt text inside a UIWebView?

So most of what you're probably going to see here on SO related to images & iOS is downloading those images to display natively inside something like a UITableView or something like that. That's probably just going to confuse the issue here.

What I would do is, inside the SQLite database, store absolute URLs (include the http:// and FDQN) for the images you want to display. Then, when you're building the HTML (which it sounds like you're then displaying using UIWebView's `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`) just insert those URLs into the appropriate  HTML tags. You can then shove that string into loadHTMLString and UIWebView should take care of loading the approriate images for you!

And yes I completely agree with whoever told you BLOBs are a Bad Thing™ in SQLite. However, I've seen some "clever" solutions with utilizing base64 encoding of images and storing the resulting string in a TEXT field in SQLite. This is *slightly* better but not by much. It's an option though if you want, and you'll just need to go get the appropriate HTML code to load a base64 image source.

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thanks. The alt text is not necessary, just the image.
In any case,what you propose sounds like what I need. Will let you know.